# Backbone render with collection

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm starting to study Backbone with requirejs

I follow some tutorial online and now I have a little doubt.
When I fetch data from  a Json print me into the console log too much line, if into my json there is 4 element, it print me 4*4 element.
This is my code:

Collection:

```
define(['backbone', 'models/todo'], function(Backbone, TodoModel){

    var todoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: TodoModel,
        url:'json/todos.json',
        parse: function(data){
            return data.result;
        }
    });

    return todoCollection;
});
```

App:

```
define(['jquery' , 'backbone', 'views/todo', 'models/todo', 'collections/todo'], 
    function($, Backbone, TodoView, TodoModel, TodoCollection){
    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el:$('#placeholder'),

        initialize: function(){
            console.log('initialize AppView');
            this.todos = new TodoCollection();
            this.todos.bind('all',this.render, this);
            this.todos.fetch();
        },
        render: function(){
            console.log('Data is fetched');
            this.todos.each(function(model){
                console.log(model.get("content"));
            });
        }
    })

    return AppView;
});
```

Json:

```
{
    "result":[
        {
            "content" : "Todo1"
        },
        {
            "content" : "Todo2"
        },
        {
            "content" : "Todo3"
        },
        {
            "content" : "Todo4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Output into the console:

```
initialize AppView app.js:8
Data is fetched app.js:14
4
Initialized Todo model todo.js:7
Data is fetched app.js:14
Todo1 app.js:16
Todo2 app.js:16
Todo3 app.js:16
Todo4 app.js:16
Data is fetched app.js:14
Todo1 app.js:16
Todo2 app.js:16
Todo3 app.js:16
Todo4 app.js:16
Data is fetched app.js:14
Todo1 app.js:16
Todo2 app.js:16
Todo3 app.js:16
Todo4 app.js:16
Data is fetched app.js:14
Todo1 app.js:16
Todo2 app.js:16
Todo3 app.js:16
Todo4 app.js:16
Data is fetched app.js:14
Todo1 app.js:16
Todo2 app.js:16
Todo3 app.js:16
Todo4 app.js:16
```

Why there is so much lines?
I expected an output like this:

```
initialize AppView app.js:8
Data is fetched app.js:14
4
Initialized Todo model todo.js:7
Data is fetched app.js:14
Todo1 app.js:16
Todo2 app.js:16
Todo3 app.js:16
Todo4 app.js:16
```

I don't understand the point. Can someone explain what am I wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
this.todos.bind('all',this.render, this);
```

You are binding to all events which in turn calls this.render several times.

Try this instead:

```
this.todos.bind('sync', this.render, this);
```

or, better yet:

```
this.todos.on('sync', this.render, this);
```

Comment: ah you bandit, I was about to post the exact same! =) +1

Comment: Or even better: `this.listenTo(this.todos, 'sync', this.render)`.